# Check if a cell contains values from a list

Tags: excel

I am trying to check if a cell contains (not equals) a value from a list.  I would prefer if the formula returned a true/false result so I can further embed it into an if function.

Sample of values in cells I want to check.  For clarity, please call these column A in suggestions.

MIA/EWR/MIA
LGA/PIT 
HKG/TPE/HKG/MNL/HKG 
LGB/IAD 
MIA/GRU/MIA 
YUL/LGA
FLL/BOG/MDE/FLL SFO/LAX/SFO

A sample of what I would like to check for is below.  I have 165 values I need to check if that makes a difference in your suggestion.  Please reference column B for this list.
BOG
BOM
GRU
JAL
MDE
MNL
THR
TUN

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Based on your description, the data setup looks like this:

[image]

In cell C2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$B$2:$B$11&"*"))>0
```

Comment: You just barely beat me to hitting post. :)

Comment: I'm getting false "TRUE" results...MIA/EWR/MIA TRUE
LGA/PIT TRUE
LGB/IAD TRUE
DCA/LAX TRUE
YUL/LGA TRUE
BOS/FLL/BOS TRUE

Comment: Sorry thats so messy...let me try again

Comment: I would need to see a sample of what is giving you false positives.  Based on the information provided and the sample set worked on, all results came out properly

Comment: Here is my formula: =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(U3,"*"&Lookup!$L$2:$L$164&"*"))>0 <br> The string from column A is in column U on my workbook and I have the values to look for on a sheet named "Lookup" if that might be the issue?

Comment: are any of the cells in your lookup range, `Lookup!$L$2:$L$164` blank? A blank cell in the lookup range will result in false positives

Comment: You can't have blanks in Lookup!$L$2:$L$164....or if you do change to `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(U3,""&Lookup!$L$2:$L$164&"")*(Lookup!$L$2:$L$164<>""))>0`

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had part of an old formula underneath (next row down on the formula bar) that was messing with me! Thank you AGAIN!

Comment: @tigeravatar: I have this bookmarked...and refer to it constantly. What a handy snippet. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just Insert the following formula in cell C2: `=NB.SI(A:A;B2)`
the result:

- **0** : if the value not exist in the list
- **[number > 0]** : if the value exist

*Note: the formula is extracted in French Excel. use that same English*

Comment: COUNTIF(range,criteria)